# Find certain text within a PHP variable string

Tags: php

Basically I'll be having a string that looks like

`#schedule take out trash #in 20`

and I need to be able to pull out "take out trash" and "20" and put them in their own variables. Possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match`, for example

```
if (preg_match('/#schedule (.+?) #in (\d+)/', $string, $matches)) {
    // found matches
    $instruction = $matches[1];
    $time = $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`list($task, $delay) = preg_split("/\s?#(\w+)\s?/")`

should work for anything in that general format unless you need to worry about people putting `#` in the task name